# Adding multiple objects to the same JSON string

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Hey all I am trying to output more than one JSON output value. In XML it would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EmployeeInformation>
  <EmployeeInfo>
    <lastName>Bob</lastName>
    <firstName>Barker</firstName>
    <eMail>bob_barker@theGameShow.com</eMail>
    <badgeID>760013224</badgeID>
  </EmployeeInfo>
  <EmployeeInfo>
    <lastName>John</lastName>
    <firstName>Doe</firstName>
    <eMail>jDoe@somewhere.com</eMail>
    <badgeID>0162000037467</badgeID>
  </EmployeeInfo>
</EmployeeInformation>
```

I would like to follow that same structure in JSON. However, I currently only am getting this output:

```
{
  "lastName": "Barker",
  "firstName": "Bob",
  "eMail": "bob_barker@theGameShow.com",
  "badgeID": "760013224",
}{
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "firstName": "John",
  "eMail": "jDoe@somewhere.com",
  "badgeID": "0162000037467",
}
```

From this code here:

```
Dim json As String = ""

empInfo.firstName = "Bob"
empInfo.lastName = "Barker"
empInfo.eMail = "bob_barker@theGameShow.com"
empInfo.badgeID = "760013224"

json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(empInfo, Formatting.Indented)

empInfo.firstName = "John"
empInfo.lastName = "Doe"
empInfo.eMail = "jDoe@somewhere.com"
empInfo.badgeID = "0162000037467"

json &= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(empInfo, Formatting.Indented)
```

So how would I go about making it structured as it is in XML using JSON.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of serializing each employee object individually, you need to add your employee objects to a list and then serialize the list:

```
Dim employees As New List(Of EmployeeInfo)
Dim empInfo As EmployeeInfo

empInfo = New EmployeeInfo()
empInfo.firstName = "Bob"
empInfo.lastName = "Barker"
empInfo.eMail = "bob_barker@theGameShow.com"
empInfo.badgeID = "760013224"
employees.Add(empInfo)

empInfo = New EmployeeInfo()
empInfo.firstName = "John"
empInfo.lastName = "Doe"
empInfo.eMail = "jDoe@somewhere.com"
empInfo.badgeID = "0162000037467"
employees.Add(empInfo)

Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees, Formatting.Indented)
Console.WriteLine(json)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Barker",
    "eMail": "bob_barker@theGameShow.com",
    "badgeID": "760013224"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "eMail": "jDoe@somewhere.com",
    "badgeID": "0162000037467"
  }
]
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M2bQqg